# C# WCF service - Access FoxPro DLL in multiuser scenario

Tags: c#, wcf, dll, foxpro, multi-user

I plan to run a WCF-Console-Application as a Windows service.
The WCF-Console-Application calls a FoxPro-DLL to access data in FoxPro-DBF (read and write). 
Different clients (WPF-Application) should consume the WCF-Service of the Console-Application to display and edit the data from the FoxPro-DBF.

If only one Client at a time calls the WCF-Console-Application, everything works fine. But the WCF-Console-Application does not handle parallel calls from multiple clients correctly.

The WCF-Console-Application consists of these classes:

- main Class: derived from ServiceBase, can be either called from console or started as service

  public class Service : ServiceBase
   {
          public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

  ```
      const string CONSOLE = "console";


      public Service()
      {
          this.ServiceName = "ServiceTest";
      }


      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
           if (args.Length == 1 && args[0].Equals(CONSOLE))
          {
              new Service().startConsole();
          }
          else
          {
              ServiceBase.Run(new Service());
          }
      }

      private void startConsole()
      {
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}::start Service...", GetType().FullName));
          OnStart(null);

          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}::ready (ENTER to stop)", GetType().FullName));
          Console.ReadLine();                                                                 

          OnStop();                                                                           

          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}::stop Service", GetType().FullName));              

      }

      protected override void OnStop()
      {
          if (this.serviceHost != null)
          {
              this.serviceHost.Close();                                    
              this.serviceHost = null;
          }
      }

      protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
      {
          if (this.serviceHost != null)
          {
              this.serviceHost.Close();                                    
          }


         this.serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Server.TestServer));              
         this.serviceHost.Open();                                         

  }
  ```
- ServiceInstaller: installs the Service, derived from Installer

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class InstallService : Installer
{
    public InstallService()
    {
        process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();                    
        process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;                             
        service= new ServiceInstaller();                                                
        service.ServiceName = "ServiceTest";                            
        service.Description = "ServiceTest";                    
        service.DisplayName = "ServiceTest";                    
        service.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;                       

        Installers.Add(process);                                    
        Installers.Add(service);                                     
    }
}
```

- static class for accessing the FoxPro-DLL

```
public static class DataAccess
{
    public static foxprotest.foxprotest accessData = new foxprotest.foxprotest();
}
```

- ITestServer, Interface with the ServiceContract

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http:/localhost.TestServer", SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface ITestServer
{
    [OperationContract]
    String loadData(int id);
}
```

- TestServer, implementation of ITestServer

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class TestServer : ITestServer
{
    public String loadData(int id)
    {
                    //set table 
        DataAccess.accessData.CTABLE = "patient";
                    //set ID 
          DataAccess.accessData.NPATIENT = id;
        //fetch the data
        DataAccess.accessData.FetchData();
                    //return data as XML
         return  DataAccess.accessData.CRESULT;
    }
}
```

This is how the App.Config looks like: the binding is set to netTcpBinding

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Server.TestServer" behaviorConfiguration="MyFileServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8888/"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:52/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="TestServer" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          name="b" contract="Server.ITestServer" />
        <endpoint address="TestServer" binding="netTcpBinding"
          name="c" contract="Server.ITestServer" />
      </service>
    </services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyFileServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="80" maxConcurrentSessions="80"
          maxConcurrentInstances="80" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I used svcutil.exe to generate the output.config and TestServer.cs for the WPF-Application.

The FoxPro-DLL is built as multi-threaded COM server, it is registered correctly and VFP9T.DLL is used. There is a little delay in the function loadData(), to test the parallel calls. When I call the DLL from multiple FoxPro-Instances, everything works as expected. If I include the dll into the WPF-Application and call it from there, it also works. Only with multiple calls through the WCF-Console-Application, it does not work correctly.

When I run the WCF-Console-Application through console and make a Console.WriteLine before every line in TestServer.LoadData(), the second call keeps hangig in front of

```
DataAccess.accessData.CTABLE = "patient";
```

until the first call is finished. The worst thing is: the returned XML-string is the same when I make parallel calls. Immediately after the first call with an ID, i start a second call with a different ID. For both calls I get the XML-String with the second ID.

What can I change, to get the parallel call to the FoxPro-DLL inside the WCF-Console-Application working? I tried every combination of InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode, without success. Do I need thread safety? If so, what do I have to change? 
The use of ODBC or a SQL-Server are no option for this project.

Thanks for any suggestion and advice!

EDIT: If I restart the WCF-Console-Application, only the first parallel test delivers wrong XML-strings. If I do a second parallel call, the returned XML-strings are correct. But the problem with the parallel call still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BasicHttpBinding` does not support sessions. You need to use `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` to make sure that every call is run in its own thread.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class TestServer : ITestServer
{
   ...
}
```

**Update:**

Is `DataAccess.accessData` `static`? If yes - that needs to be changed. Static data is shared across multiple threads. Therefore service can return data updated by another call if `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` is used.  `ConcurrencyMode.Single` still can be used with mutable static data but you will get all scalability issues of single thread.

Comment: The BasicHttpBinding is only used to get the informations about the WCF-service with svcutil.exe. If I remove the endpoint for the BasicHttpBinding and change the InstanceContextMode to PerCall nothing changes. The behaviour is still the same.

Edit: How can I check on server-side, which binding is used?

Comment: Indeed, DataAccas.accessData is static. If I change this, everything works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: It's quite embarassing, but the parallel data access is not working again. I extended the WCF-Service with two ServiceContracts (file transfer, start of an external exe). I made two new CS-Files for the interfaces and two additional CS-Files with partial classes. Both worked like expected, but somehow the parallel data access broke down. I'm not sure, if it has to do with the extension, because if I make a blank project with the code above, it is not working as well. There are no static variables, it's still PerCall. Could it depend on how I include the dll into my project?